# QThread finished() connected to deletelater of a QObject

Tags: c++, signals, exit, qthread, qobject

I have thought a lot and read lot of articles before asking this question here. None of the articles gave me a proper answer.

http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

```
 QThread* thread = new QThread;
 Worker* worker = new Worker();
 worker->moveToThread(thread);
 connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
 connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
 connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
 connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
 connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
 thread->start();
```

Worker object has the affinity of the new thread.

1. Worker finished signal will call `quit()` on the thread. This will end the thread's event loop and initiates the thread finished signal.
2. Worker `finished` signal is connected to the worker `deleteLater()`. According to `deleteLater()` documentation

> Schedules this object for deletion.
> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop.
> If the event loop is not running
> when this function is called (e.g. `deleteLater()` is called on an
> object before `QCoreApplication::exec()`), the object will be deleted
> once the event loop is started.
>
> Note that entering and leaving a new
> event loop (e.g., by opening a modal dialog) will not perform the
> deferred deletion; for the object to be deleted, the control must
> return to the event loop from which `deleteLater()` was called.

> Note: It
> is safe to call this function more than once; when the first deferred
> deletion event is delivered, any pending events for the object are
> removed from the event queue.**

So when there is no event loop, since the thread is already exiting and  it has already raised the finished signal and we will no longer start the same thread again.  In  this case the `deleteLater()` will never be handled since the event loop doesn't exist and and worker object will not be deleted at all. Does this not create a memory leak.?

```
 connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
 connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
```

If we think that swapping the two lines will fix the problem, then I have another question. QT clearly states that the order the slots getting called when a signal is emitted is undetermined

There are bunch of comments in the article link mentioned above . Even the author was not able to answer the question completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QThread will do a [QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#sendPostedEvents) with a event type of QEvent::DeferredDelete after sending it's finished signal

in other words QThread will collect all pending deleteLaters and execute them after `run` returns

source: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/c657bb7b51115d6e1719166fb502bb0ca1dcf4e8:src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp#L363-462

Comment: Your link (the source one) is not working. But as stated in the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished) : "When this signal [`finished`] is emitted, the event loop has already stopped running. No more events will be processed in the thread, *except for deferred deletion events*. This signal can be connected to QObject::deleteLater(), to free objects in that thread."

Answer (score 2):

```
//! put the following code in constructor
QThread *thread = new QThread;
//! type of m_weakThread is QWeakPointer<QThread>
m_weakThread = thread;
Worker *worker = new Worker;
//! type of m_weakWorker is QWeakPointer<Worker>
m_weakWorker = worker;
worker->moveToThread(thread);
connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
//! instead of finished() signal, connect destroyed() signal to thread's quit() slot
connect(worker, SIGNAL(destroyed()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread->start();

//! put the following code in destructor
if (!m_weakThread.isNull()) {
    QThread *thread = m_weakThread.data();
    if (thread->isRunning()) {
        thread->quit();
        thread->wait();
    }
}
if (!m_weakWorker.isNull()) {
    Worker *worker = m_weakWorker.data();
    m_weakWorker.clear();   //! optional, a little optimization
    //! it's safe to release worker since the secondary thread exits
    delete worker;
}
if (!m_weakThread.isNull()) {
    QThread *thread = m_weakThread.data();
    m_weakThread.clear();
    //! it's safe to release thread since it exits and all objects in it has released
    delete thread;
}
```

Comment: You cannot  delete the worker in the created object thread. since it has already been moved to the Thread using moveToThread. Can you explain this.

Comment: Also I would advise assigning a parent to `QThread`. Since the instance of `QThread` is part of the thread where it was spawned (unlike any objects that have been moved to it or its `run()` method) it is perfectly safe to do `thread = new QThread(this);` if `thread` is to be part of some other class. In general you should avoid calling `delete` if there is a better non-manual solution. Even in the standard C++ you have smart pointers and what not which takes the burden of manually cleaning up off of your shoulders.