# How can I fix this memory leak when using Qt smart pointers and deleteLater()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

I have a class `WorkerThreadManager` that creates and owns a number of Qt threads:

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WorkerThread() : QThread()
    {
        start();
    }

    virtual ~SearchCacheWorkerThread()
    {
        quit();
        wait();
    }
    
    virtual void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        // fetch from mysql
        // process results
        // append many new items to results_
    
        quit();
    }

private:
    QList<int> results_;
};
typedef QSharedPointer<WorkerThread> WorkerThreadPtr;

class WorkerThreadManager : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WorkerThreadManager(const int numThreads) : QObject()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i )
        {
            threads_ << WorkerThreadPtr( new WorkerThread(), &QObject::deleteLater );
        }
    }
    virtual ~WorkerThreadManager() {}

private:
    QList<WorkerThreadPtr> threads_;
```

When I destroy the `WorkerThreadManager` object, I don't see the memory being released.

I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12114604) that the `deleteLater` won't do anything if the thread has exited the event loop. So I changed the code to remove all calls to `quit()` in order to ensure a thread stays in the event loop until deleteLater is called. But I still get the memory leak.

1. What's the correct way to destroy the threads (preferrably with the use of smart pointers)?
2. How do I ensure that the threads will finish before they get destroyed, even if their destructor is called?

Comment: Do you actually need a custom deleter here? When the shared pointer is destroyed, it should delete its contents right away, assuming there are no other shared pointers referencing it.

Comment: https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

Comment: Also I recommend not using threads. In 99% of cases signals and slots are working great on single thread. In other cases use of QtConcurrent is more handy then `QThread`

Comment: There is a specific pattern for deleting QObjects living in a thread which terminates: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#details

Comment: @JarMan and how do I get a guarantee that there's no slot being handled at the point of the deletion? Isn't that the point of `deleteLater`?

Comment: @MarekR I totally agree. But this is production code and it wasn't written by me. I need a very good reason to justify changing the framework instead of fixing it.

Comment: Living aside best practices, isn't `deleteLater()` supposed to be safer than plain `delete`? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JarMan mentioned in a comment, it doesn't seem necessary (at least from the provided snippet) to have a custom deleter for your shared pointer.

If you've already tried removing the deleter, and you still observed the problem, it's possible that someone is still holding a reference to the thread object. To be absolutely sure that's not the case, try using a `QScopedPointer` instead, which is similar to `std::unique_ptr`.

This should provide a runtime error if you're passing your smart pointer by value and some other code is attempting to store it, and then you'll know where you should switch to using a raw pointer type (`WorkerThread*`).

It's hard to know for sure without more code, but a common cause for this issue is capturing a shared pointer by value in a lambda used in a signal/slot connection. Based on what you've provided, is it possible you've done this? I see your workers have the member `results_`, are you consuming these results on the main thread through a signal emitted from your worker?

Lastly, as Marek R mentioned in the comments, it would be a much safer idea to use worker objects (described in the Qt blog thread they linked) instead of subclassing QThread. QtConcurrent is also an excellent choice if you don't need much control over the thread and only want some calculations to occur in another thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At this point I'm trying to understand the Qt framework better so that I eliminate cases for the memory leak.
The `results_` are consumed by a handler thread that tries to read them. The main thread though is the one that owns the manager objects.
I know the worker objects are a better / the suggested way but at this point I'm trying to find out where the problem is.
Is it safe to use `deleteLater()` with smart pointers for QThread subclasses? If not, why?

Comment: Also, can I safely call the destructor of the manager (and subsequently of the threads) from a handler thread (as in **not** the thread that created the object)?

Comment: "`results_` are consumed by a handler thread that tries to read them"  
Are you establishing a connection to a signal from your workers? Is the slot its connected to a lambda? Please double check that you're not prolonging the life of your shared pointers. If you haven't yet, try the QScopedPointer trick first.  

`deleteLater()` is for when you want an object to be deleted in the next event loop cycle, which prevents any currently queued events from trying to use a null object. You can use it in a smart pointer, but since this is a shared pointer, this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Shared pointers, by default, ensure that if some code is still using the object, it will not be deleted. Using `deleteLater()` just prolongs the lifetime by one more event loop cycle before deleting it, which probably doesn't do anything useful in this case.

And **no**, you should not manually call a destructor on an object, especially from another thread. This is what `deleteLater()` would be useful for. The destruction of an object should be done on the thread in which it lives, and `deleteLater()` creates an event to schedule the object for deletion in its own thread.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found where the problem was. There's still a memory leak but that's a separate issue.
At least I got a better idea of how the Qt threads are managed.